# Difference between SpringBeanFacesELResolver and DelegatingVariableResolver

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I want to integrate JSF with Spring Framework. I used `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` class on `faces-config.xml`,everythink works fine.My question is, what is the difference between `org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver` and  `org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver` ?

Comment: `DelegatingVariableResolver` is for JSF 1.1 (and has been removed in Spring 4.x and onwards), `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` is for JSF 1.2 and up.

Comment: @M. Denium tyvm :)

Comment: @M.Denium: please write it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2
[`DelegatingVariableResolver`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3.2.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/jsf/DelegatingVariableResolver.java) is for JSF 1.1 (and has been removed in Spring 4.x and onwards), [`SpringBeanFacesELResolver`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/jsf/el/SpringBeanFacesELResolver.java) is for JSF 1.2 and up.

The `DelegatingVariableResolver` only exists upon Spring Framework 3.2 in which it got deprecated. As of Spring Framework 4.0 this class doesn’t exists anymore.